# ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage does not create a Title area

Tags: modern-pages, conversion, missing

I have used the following PowerShell command to convert some of my classic pages to modern:

`ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage`

The pages look OK, however it is missing the top Title area. How do I create/re-add that missing piece?

Comment: I was surprised there doesn't appear to be an option for this. Only way I've found so far is to edit the pages by hand and add the title image

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set-PnPClientSidePage`with the switch `HeaderType` afterwards.

Please also see:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps